# How do I create a file descriptor backed by a simple char array?

Tags: c, unit-testing, file-descriptor

I have a function that receives a descriptor (you know, one of those things that [`open()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) and [`socket()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html) spit), reads from it and does something with the data:

```
int do_something(int fd);
```

I want to test this function. Preferably, the input data should sit right next to the test assert for the sake of easy debugging. (Therefore, actual file reading should be avoided.) In my mind, the ideal would be something like

```
unsigned char test_input[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
int fd = char_array_to_fd(test_input);
ck_assert(do_something(fd) == 1234);
```

(`ck_assert` is from the [Check framework](http://check.sourceforge.net/doc/check_html/index.html). It's just a typical unit test assert.)

Is there a way to implement `char_array_to_fd()`? I don't mind if I need to NULL-terminate the array or send the length in.

I imagine that I can open a socket to myself and write on one end so the test function receives the data on the other end. I just don't want to write something awkward and find out that Unix had something less contrived all along. The solution should be any-Unix friendly.

(Basically, I'm asking for a C equivalent of [`ByteArrayInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html).)

Alternatively: Should I be thinking in some other way to solve this problem?

Comment: Why not split the functionality, so you have one function which reads the text from the descriptor, then passes it on to another function which could be easily testable by itself.

Comment: But if you want to test the reading from the descriptor, then you could use pipes.

Comment: Well, I don't really know how large the input data will be. Its length is described by a 32-bit unsigned integer representing octets.

Comment: I concur with @Someprogrammerdude. Without rearchitecting, the simplest thing would probably be a [pipe pair](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html), fed your input array by your test wrapper.

Comment: Ooh. Pipes are interesting.

Comment: @Dipstick I should probably make as few assumptions regarding my environment as possible. "Reasonably Unix"; that's all.

Comment: [`fmemopen()` is POSIX.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fmemopen.html) That should make it "Reasonably Unix" enough.

Comment: @AndrewHenle True.

Comment: This idea didn't exist in historical unix for a reason: File descriptors were an abstract interface to several types of objects, but all of those objects were things implemented by the kernel. They were ways for data to enter or leave a process. Copying data from one place in your address space to another (in the same process) is in a separate class of problems.

Comment: @dipstick: i don't believe that `fileno` works on `fmemopen`d `FILE*`s

Comment: @dipstick: from `man fmemstream` (on linux): "There is no file descriptor associated with the file stream returned by this function (i.e., `fileno(3)` will return an error if called on the returned stream)."

Comment: @nkhail: do you really only want to mock `read()`? You'll never want to mock `write()`? `seek()`? `ioctl()`? Socket functions? (Not that I'm saying I have a solution in mind. I just want to know the parameters before I think about it more.)

Comment: @rici `read()` only, at least for now. But if you find a more versatile solution than what has already been posted, I wouldn't mind changing the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mkstemp` to make a temporary file and write to it or read from it:

```
int fd = mkstemp("tempXXXXXX");
```

If you want something more dynamic, you can use `socketpair` to create a pair of connected sockets.

```
int pair[2];
socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, pair);
```

You can then fork process or thread to interact with your program under test.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know if there are advantages or disadvantages of using the socket pair vs the pipe pair described in the question's comment stack?

Comment: @nkhailhna: pipes are unidirectional (one end is read only, the other is write only), while socketpairs are bidirectional (both ends are read-write)

Answer (score 3):

On Linux, you can use [`memfd_create()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/memfd_create.2.html) to create a memory-backed temporary file:

```
unsigned char test_input[] = ...;

int fd = memfd_create( "test_input", 0 );

// write test data to the the "file"
write( fd, test_input, sizeof( test_input );

// reset file descriptor to the start of the "file"
lseek( fd, 0, SEEK_SET );
```

Note that completely lacks error checking.

Comment: This'd be nice, but it does not exist in the BSDs if their man pages are anything to go by :/

Comment: @nkhailhna From the linked manual page: "The memfd_create() system call is Linux-specific."

Comment: Right. My point is that I value this contribution, particularly since it can help somebody who is dropped here by some search engine. But it doesn't match the "any-Unix friendly" clause.

Answer (score 0):

@ChrisDodd's answer is already accepted, but I wanted to add the pipes solution I had developed (thanks to @Someprogrammerdude's comment) for completeness sake:

```
struct writer_args {
    int fd;
    unsigned char *buffer;
    size_t size;
};

/* Pipe writer thread function */
void *write_buffer(void *_args)
{
    struct writer_args *args = _args;
    /*
     * error handling omitted.
     * Should probably also be thrown into a loop, in case it writes less
     * than args->size.
     */
    write(args->fd, args->buffer, args->size);
    close(args->fd);
    return NULL;
}

/*
 * Wrapper for quick & easy testing of the do_something() function.
 * Replaces the fd parameter for a char array and its size.
 */
static int __do_something(unsigned char *input, size_t size)
{
    pthread_t writer_thread;
    struct writer_args args;
    int fd[2];
    int result;

    pipe(fd); /* error handling omitted */
    /* fd[0] is for reading, fd[1] is for writing */

    /*
     * We want one thread for reading, another one for writing.
     * This is because pipes have a nonstandardized maximum buffer capacity.
     * If we write too much without reading, it will block forever.
     */
    args.fd = fd[1];
    args.buffer = input;
    args.size = size;
    /* error handling omitted */
    pthread_create(&writer_thread, NULL, write_buffer, &args);

    result = do_something(fd[0]);
    close(fd[0]);

    pthread_join(writer_thread, NULL); /* error handling omitted */

    return result;
}
```

Then, I can keep testing `do_something` as much as I want:

```
ret = __do_something(input1, input1_size);
if (ret != 1234)
    fprintf(stderr, "Fail. Expected:1234 Actual:%d\n", ret);

ret = __do_something(input2, input2_size);
if (ret != 0)
    fprintf(stderr, "Fail. Expected:0 Actual:%d\n", ret);

ret = __do_something(input3, input3_size);
if (ret != 555)
    fprintf(stderr, "Fail. Expected:555 Actual:%d\n", ret);

...
```

Comment: Isn't that solution possibly blocking?

Comment: Indeed. Might end up having to delete this answer. I'll try to improve it first.

Comment: Done. Tested using actual large buffers this time.